# Photoshop: Embed linked files

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Ok, so now here's the deal: I have been working on a .psd for a while now, using linked smart objects. Now it is time to hand it off to someone else. Is there some kind of possibility to embed all those linked files at once? Or do I have to go through every single one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, it seems like I am slowly going blind ...

[image: screencapture]

Answer (score 0):

there are few other possibilities 
The are more two cases:

- Already created objects:

  1. convert it;

[image]

2. relink it;

[image]

(you may set a hot key to faster these actions)

- Stored file to make it ***Smart*** and ***Linked*** object at once. Click `Place linked`. With this command you may upload a pile of files at once.

[image]

Uptodate Photoshop updates links at the fly.